# Randomising a modifier within a python instance

Tags: python

I am building a simple crowd system and wish to instantiate a mesh that has a MESH_CACHE modifier on it. I wish each instance to have a new random value for the frame offset of each instance.
I have no problem instancing, using the by.ops.object.group_instance_add.... command. However, even if I add an expression on a driver within the Modifier, randomising the frame offset based on position. Each instance references the original position, not it's new one. Thus all instances have the same offset.

Any help appreciated. R

Comment: I guess you should use the instance (or group instance) index for dif values on the whole list

Comment: Hmm. Not sure exactly how that will help me. And how I could even get any randomly seeded (by the index) number to drive the frame offset for the unique Mesh cache modifier. Would you be able to elaborate a little?